# jwplayer не воспроизводит hls, почему?

Tags: html5, видео, mediaplayer, streaming, hls

Доброго времени суток. Решил я организовать live видео трансляции с нескольких устройств, так или иначе пришел к тому что надо это делать с помощью hls, все работает, все хорошо. Решил на веб морде вывести их и улицезреть. Долго копаясь, так или иначе выбрал jwplayer. Зарегистрировался, получил ключ, скачал, кинул на сервер, создал html страничку. Результат - **НЕ РАБОТАЕТ**, какой бы адрес hls я не вставлял, результат один - ЖИЗНЬ БОЛЬ! Вообщем я убил очень много времени и не нашел ошибку, дорогие пользователи stackoverflow помогите решить мою проблему пожалуйста, **подскажите что я делаю не так** и направьте на путь истинный. 
Предположим у нас есть следующая ссылка hls:
http://esioslive6-i.akamaihd.net/hls/live/202892/AL_P_ESP1_FR_FRA/playlist.m3u8
Я проверил на https://www.hlsplayer.net/ , все работает.
И вот моя демонстративная html страничка

```
<!DOCTYPE> 
 <html>
    <head>
        <!-- ссылка на плеер, взял с сайта  -->
        <script src='https://content.jwplatform.com/libraries/7XBRYUMN.js'></script>
        <!-- мой ключ  -->
        <script>jwplayer.key="***";</script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="my-video"></div>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            jwplayer("my-video").setup({
                file: "http://esioslive6-i.akamaihd.net/hls/live/202892/AL_P_ESP1_FR_FRA/playlist.m3u8",
                width: 400,
                height: 240,
                title: "клип",
                hlshtml: true,
                type: "hls",
                androidhls: true
            });
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Если плеер скачать с сайта и его подключить, результат аналогичный. Пробовал скачать старые версии плеера, результат тот же. Пробовал воспользоваться вот этой статьей, http://rugraphics.ru/forvideo/besplatnyy-jw-player-dlya-sayta результат аналогичный=( Такое ощущение что jw player не поддерживает hls, но я нашел вот эту страницу http://demo.jwplayer.com/stream-tester/ и убедился в том что он должен это делать!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ну вы намутили. Во первых тот скрипт, который вы называете плеером, на самом деле является полным embed скриптом, который создает заранее заданный плеер с заранее заданным ключом и так далее. Ключ там кстати free, по этому не поддерживает hls формат (вам нужен premium или выше). Далее, ключ который вы задаете ниже, плеер не принимает, поскольку single line embed player ищет ключ из другого места.

Я бы вам рекомендовал написать в support@jwplayer.com, там сидят очень добрые люди, которые вам с удовольствием помогут.

Comment: https://www.wowza.com/forums/content.php?693-How-to-play-a-Wowza-Streaming-Cloud-live-stream-in-JW-Player